# asterisk CLI with non root user

Tags: php, centos7, asterisk, pbx

I'm developing a web application to manages my asterisk server ( adding extension, adding contexts managing clients, etc.. ) I'm using PHP, Mysql to do that, I used the database to add clients but for an extension, I still use the file extensions.conf.
let's suppose that I added many extensions to the extensions.conf file from the web app, next I should reload the dialplan, the only way I know is by typing this command into the Asterisk CLI:

```
dialplan reload
```

so if I want to reload the dialplan from the web app I should run somewhere :

```
shell_exec ( "asterisk -rx 'dialplan reload'" );
```

the problem is this command `asterisk -rx` needs root privileges.
is there a way to let the apache user run this command.

**Edite :**

this is the content of my /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf file

```
[directories](!)
astetcdir => /etc/asterisk
astmoddir => /usr/lib/asterisk/modules
astvarlibdir => /var/lib/asterisk
astdbdir => /var/lib/asterisk
astkeydir => /var/lib/asterisk
astdatadir => /var/lib/asterisk
astagidir => /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
astspooldir => /var/spool/asterisk
[options]
astrundir => /var/run/asterisk
astlogdir => /var/log/asterisk
astsbindir => /usr/sbin
runuser = asterisk ; The user to run as. The default is root.
rungroup = asterisk ; The group to run as. The default is root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command NOT need root privileges.

Check /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf for file and permissions used.

Comment: I will provide my asterisk.conf in the question in till me what is the problem, please

Comment: "runuser = asterisk" so you should use asterisk user or change user on webserver/or user for asterisk be same as webserver

Comment: thank you very much for answering, is there a way by adding the apache user to the same group as the asterisk user

Comment: Yes, but you have change astctlpermissions  to be group-writable https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-config-asteriskconf/

Comment: thank you very much, it works for me but I wanna know where I can learn more about why it didn't work for the first time and wy it works now. I mean what astctlpermissions does

Comment: Asterisk console(what you use via asterisk -r) send commands via pipe to asterisk. That pipe permissions defined in asterisk.conf. For security reason it not allow ANY user acess file, read more about linux permissions system.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sudoers` (not recommended) to allow for execution of specific user to run:

```
sudo asterisk -rx 'dialplan reload'
```

and you can call that from your user, although this is dangerous if that is your web user...

### Or you can use AMI

To execute a command via `Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)` you can create yourself a user in `manager.conf` and then from PHP use a script to auth and execute a command. Example:

```
<?php
    $socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$socket){
        echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
    }else{
        fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "UserName: myusername\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Secret: mypassword\r\n\r\n");

        fputs($socket, "Action: Command\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Command: dialplan reload\r\n\r\n");

        fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");
        while (!feof($socket)){
            echo fgets($socket).'<br>';
        }
        fclose($socket);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for answering. I will learn about AMI later.